# Conditional select on associated record in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-5

I need to count the amount of retail units associated with products and also get the image from a retail unit that is in a specific position the count part works fine but I can't figure out how to select with a condition. I also need fields from the Product.

This is what I have

Product -> has_many :retail_units

RetailUnit -> belongs_to :product

```rb
Product.joins(:retail_units)
.select(:id, :name, "COUNT(retail_units.id) AS retail_units_total")
.group(:id)
```

I assume I need to do something like

```rb
Product.joins(:retail_units)
.select(:id, :name, "COUNT(retail_units.id) AS retail_units_total, retail_units.image WHERE retail_units.position = 1")
.group(:id)
```

But I can't quite figure out the syntax.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this?

```
Product.joins(:retail_units)
.select(:id, :name, "COUNT(retail_units.id) AS retail_units_total")
.where(retail_units: { position: 1 } )
.includes(:retail_units)
.group(:id)
```

Walking through [the guides](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html) is always useful.